# How to get app insights working on an azure webjob with .net core 2.x?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a webjob with .net core 2.1

I have an instrumentation key on the appsettings.json.

and I have this on the method ConfigureServices in program.cs

```
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

However, I get this error when the app starts

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.DefaultApplicationInsightsServiceConfigureOptions'.'
```

I havent been able to find any documentation that can help me with this

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to call `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();` to enable application insights.

See also the relevant warning in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#logging-services) (also applies to webjobs):

> - Do not add AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry() to the services collection as it registers services that conflict with services provided by the environment.

This is also mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4663) in which someone has exactly the same problem.

Comment: By following the link I can't see how to solve the issue. All I read is something like "apparently this is an unsupported scenario". In other hand, if AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry() should not be called, then what is needed to telemetry to AI?

Comment: @zameb the framework already provides access to application insights so thats why it isn't necessary to add the AI NuGet package and call `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry`